# Exclude a substring in htaccess RewriteRule redirect

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I manage an old site with multiple domain with the same name, 
google has indexed some old url with the language structure

```
http://www.example.com/eng/whatever
```

and

```
http://www.example.it/eng/whatever
```

and now I don't use this structure anymore, but I want to do a redirect to my new structure

```
http://www.example.it/en/whatever
```

so everything after the */eng/* must be appended to the new structure, excluded the */eng/* substring.
But it doesn't work, I have a redirect to

```
http://www.example.it/en/eng/whatever
```

which is wrong! I did not want */eng* in the redirect url

In my .htaccess I have this

```
#this will redirect the url with /eng/whatever to www.example.it/en/whatever, regardless from the top level domain
RewriteRule ^eng\/(.*)$ http://www.example.it/en/$1 [R=301,L]

#redirect example.com on www.example.it/en/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.:]+\.)*example\.(com|pt)?(:[0-9]*)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.it/en/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing all of that with just this:

```
RewriteRule ^eng/(.*) en/$1 [R,L,NE,DPI]
```

If it works, you can change the `R` to `R=301`

**Warning**

To test this, you must use a new browser. This is because browsers cache 301 redirects, so your current browser will keep redirecting to the old (wrong page) without even talking to your server and hitting the new `.htaccess`—unless you clear the browser cache.

Comment: I did test it, it works! I didn't know about NE and DPI flag.
very useful, thank you!

Comment: OK, I didn't read the rules, sorry 
thank you for your explantaion

Comment: You don't have to use a new browser. As of 2021, if you're on Chrome or Edge (chromium) you can open the developer tools and in the Network tab, toggle Disable Cache on.